# Wordpress Thumbnail link

Tags: php, wordpress

how can I add a link to a thumbnail on Wordpress

```
$output .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'Dave-profile', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
```

I tried to add

```
<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'"></a>
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<?php echo $image[0]; ?>
```

Use the above code.
If you need to change the size replace "single-post-thumbnail"

thumbnail, medium, large, full

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by many ways, one of the way is:

```
if (has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID()))
{
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '">';
    $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'Dave-profile', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
    $output .= '</a>';
}
```

Hope this helps!